# OS X Chrome, drag URL to desktop

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome

On Chrome for OS X, is it possible to create a shortcut (bookmark) by dragging the star (to the left of the URL) to the desktop or folder? This works on Chrome for Windows but not for the Mac.

**Follow up**: My OS X Google Chrome does not have the globe icon left of the URL. It looks like this:

[image: Google Chrome on OS X]

Comment: Works for me if you mean the globe on the left of the URL rather than the star on the far right.

Comment: On my OS X Chrome (5.0.375.86), to the left of the URL is a star, and to the right is a right facing triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, if i select the address in the address bar, (a little tricky, must select all, wait a tick, and click the selection) and drag that to the finder, a bookmark is created.

Agree that it is annoying that google doesn't keep such a simple behaviour consistent across platforms. It's one thing to adjust UI elements to fit the platform (ie. standard close/zoom controls on the left) and quite another to leave out cross-platform behaviours (ie. the star dragging a bookmark) and expected behaviours (ie. on Mac Safari/Firefox dragging the favicon drags an url bookmark.)

Answer (score 3):

Since your original post, Chrome now has an information icon to the left of the url/search bar (see screenshot below). If you click, hold and then drag you'll be able to save a link of the webpage to the desktop or Finder.

[image]

This seems to be the only way to do it now - at least I can't get the "select all, wait a tick and click for selection" to work like I used to be able to.

Comment: Today the icon is a warm and cuddly padlock. Works as described here.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on mac. It turned out the url was just too long. I had typed a long note into chrome and wanted to drag it to the desktop as a reminder. When I reduced the size of the google search, it let me drag and drop the link like usual. I'm assuming it was larger than the max file name in finder, but I didn't bother to confirm that. Not great that there is zero feedback and it just fails.